# getting related subjects for student in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get subjects, which student has been enrolled using MySQL.

Student Table :

[image: Student table format]

subjects table :

[image: Subject table format]

student enrolled subjects :

[image: stu_subjects table format]

My query :

```
select *,(select  subject_id from  stu_subjects ss where ss.student_id = 
s.student_id ) as subject_id
from student s
```

when executing above query I'm getting below error :

[image: Error]

So i modified my query as below (added limit 1) :

```
select *,(select  subject_id from  stu_subjects ss where ss.student_id = 
s.student_id limit 1) as subject_id
from student s
```

Final Output : 
[image: final output]

If you see the output I'm getting only one subject mapped to a student. But I need every subject which student has enrolled. So how can I achieve it?

What I'm trying to achieve is :
[image: What I'm trying to achieve is]

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought Jagrut Sharma's answer is correct, this version specifies the separator of the subjects' ids, and uses an explicit `JOIN` rather than the implicit one.

**Edit**: It appears that `,` is the default separator, so you can omit it from `GROUP_CONCAT`. I'll leave it there in my query just so you know how to change it, if needed.

```
SELECT st.student_id, st.student_name
       GROUP_CONCAT(sb.subject_id SEPARATOR ',')
FROM stu_subjects sb JOIN student st ON sb.student_id = st.student_id
GROUP BY st.student_id;
```

Comment: It wasn't a cross product. It was an implicit join - but I agree that it's better to use explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select a.student_id, b.student_name, group_concat(a.subject_id) as student_enrollment
from stu_subjects a, student b
where a.student_id = b.student_id
group by a.student_id, b.student_name;
```

**Illustration:**

```
-- table: student
> select * from student;
+------------+--------------+
| student_id | student_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Student-1    |
|          2 | Student-2    |
+------------+--------------+

-- table: subject
> select * from subject;
+------------+--------------+
| subject_id | subject_name |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Maths        |
|          2 | Science      |
|          3 | English      |
|          4 | Telugu       |
|          5 | Social       |
+------------+--------------+

-- table: stu_subjects
> select * from stu_subjects;
+------------+------------+------------+
| stu_sub_id | student_id | subject_id |
+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |          1 |          1 |
|          2 |          1 |          2 |
|          3 |          1 |          3 |
|          4 |          2 |          4 |
|          5 |          2 |          1 |
+------------+------------+------------+

-- query
> select a.student_id, b.student_name, group_concat(a.subject_id) as student_enrollment
from stu_subjects a, student b
where a.student_id = b.student_id
group by a.student_id, b.student_name;

+------------+--------------+--------------------+
| student_id | student_name | student_enrollment |
+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|          1 | Student-1    | 3,1,2              |
|          2 | Student-2    | 4,1                |
+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple join query to achieve this.

```
SELECT st.student_id,st.student_name,sb.subject_name
FROM student st 
JOIN stu_subjects ss ON (ss.student_id = st.student_id)
JOIN Subject  sb ON (ss.subject_id = sb.subject_id )
```

Also as you mentioned,if you want only for subject MySQL, then add below where condition

```
WHERE subject_name ='MySQL'
```